# PHP displaying links based on user permissions?

Tags: php, permissions, hyperlink

I'm trying to show or not show links based on a users access level. The links will be different depending on the section of the site the user might be in. The links also may not all be in one menu. They will more than likely be in various places on the page.

Currently I have a database table that contains Users, Groups and Sections. The main menu is built from the Sections database table. I'm thinking I should create an Actions table and add a link that I'd like to show for each section in the action menu. So, my tables so far are like.

```
Users
user_id

Groups
group_id
group_title

Sections
section_id
section_title
```

Table I'm thinking of adding.

```
Actions
action_id
action_title
action_group_id 
action_section_id
```

The part I'm not sure on is should I add the same link multiple times to the Actions table for each group that is allowed access. Or, just add it once and do a if group id is greater than, then show link.

Example for entering the same link multiple times.

```
action_id   action_title    action_group_id     action_section_id
1           View all        1                   1
2           View all        2                   1
3           View all        3                   1
```

I was hoping to not flood the page with a bunch of if/then statements. Plus, this doesn't seem like the best way to handle because it requires human interpretation as to what the access levels stand for.

Any help on this is appreciated. I could be going in the complete wrong direction here?

Answer (score 2):

Create a many to many relationship with an additional table where you insert an entry for each permission the group has access to. Am I correct in assuming section is what you're creating permission to?

```
Table: Group_Section (Or whatever you'd like to name it)

Group_id | Section_ID
---------+-----------
       1 |         1
       1 |         2
       1 |         3
       2 |         1
       2 |         3
         |
```

You can see that the Group with ID = 1 can access sections 1,2,3 while Group with ID = 2 can access only 1,3. You can then add whatever permissions to the table you want and manage them through the use of foreign keys.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though, I'm not really trying to restrict access to the sections. I'm really trying to come up with a simple way to hide or show links on a section the user already has access to. So, user A and B both have access to a section. But only user A can edit. User B can only view. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I suppose you could add an additional column specifying the *type* of permission such as read/edit. The table helps create the relationship between the distinct data sets allowing multiple groups to share multiple permissions, what you do to go about specifying the amount of permissions might be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article but the things are discussed in general http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control)

In your case, use what `TheCapn` wrote and I'll just add, that its 'best to start session for every user and just check his access level when he's trying to reach a restricted part.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, to do this kind of thing, i set a user level in the user table and a section level in the section table.
Then you simply have to filter the section according to your user level.

You can do this by adding a statemtn to you sql like

```
AND section_level >= "user_level";
```

or then again, get all the section and filter tham with php.

```
foreach($section as $s){
 if ($s->level >= user_level) echo $s->title
}
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust the <. = and > according to the hierachy of your system.

I personnaly use a lowering hierachy, meaning, the lower the level you are the more right you have. This way you can make a 'banned' user by setting his level to 99 or something.

THis would be only for your menus, make sure you control the user_level on each page as well so if someone get to the page directly it get kicked..

Hope it points your in the right direction. ;)